# Unhandled exception at 0x001066F6 in task2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000C

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I wrote the code below as part of a school assignment. It sorts an array of object pointers based on the student ID, which is a private int between 100 and 999. But for some reason I get the following error on the getId function when debugging in VS12:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x001066F6 in task2.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000C.
```

This is the code where getId is used:

```
if (nr_of_students > 1) {
    int pre = nr_of_students - 1;
    int current = nr_of_students;
    Student* temp;
    // This pause will run:
    system("pause");
    while (pre > 0 && students[pre]->getId() > students[current]->getId()) {
        // This pause will NOT run:
        system("pause");
        temp = students[current];
        students[current] = students[pre];
        students[pre] = temp;
        pre--;
        current--;
    }
}
```

The code for Student class:

```
class Student : public Person {
private:
    int id;
    /* Other variables */
public:

    /* Constructors and functions */

    int getId() {
        return id;
    }
};
```

What the hell is going on?

Comment: _'What the hell is going on?'_ Most probably you are dereferencing an invalid (`NULL`) pointer.

Comment: Maybe the built-in debugger may be of some help? Like maybe tell you which line generates the error?

Comment: I only get the error when using the debugger, otherwise it just crashes. The debugger says the error is on the line where it returns id from the getId function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probable reason based on the provided information:

`current` is equal to `nr_of_students`, and in

```
 while (pre > 0 && students[pre]->getId() > students[current]->getId())
```

`current` is used as array index. Since array index start from `zero`, this will be a problem if `nr_of_students` is actually equal to the *number of elements* in the array. For ex. if there are  `5`  elements, then maximum index can be `4`, not `5`. If you use `5`, the memory location is invalid, which will return invalid `Student*`, and calling `getId()` with this invalid pointer will cause *access violation error*.